# Is it possible to marshal a Calendar value to an epoch long in JSON format using MOXy?

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, moxy

I have an app that uses JAXB and Jersey (using MOXy for the JSON provider), and need to serialize to JSON in which `java.util.Calendar` objects get converted to epoch values.  So far I have tried:

1) do nothing an allow default conversion to happen:

```
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class Foo {
    @XmlSchemaType( name = "dateTime" )
    protected Calendar time;

    public Calendar getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime( Calendar value ) {
        this.time = value;
    }
}
```

Which results in ISO-8601:

```
{
   "foo" : {
      "time" : "2016-06-06T17:52:31.593-04:00"
   }
}
```

2) Use an adapter to convert it to a long:

```
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class Foo {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter( CalendarAdapter.class )
    @XmlSchemaType( name = "dateTime" )
    protected Calendar time;

    public Calendar getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime( Calendar value ) {
        this.time = value;
    }
}
```

Which results in an epoch value, but as a *STRING*:

```
{
   "foo" : {
      "time" : "1465250094634"
   }
}
```

3) This variation of 2:

```
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class Foo {
    @XmlElement( type = String.class )
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter( CalendarAdapter.class )
    @XmlSchemaType( name = "dateTime" )
    protected Calendar time;

    public Calendar getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime( Calendar value ) {
        this.time = value;
    }
}
```

In which the `@XmlElement` is added to set the type to `String` which is what you get when you generate the java pojo using xjc and this definition:

```
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime" 
          adapter="org.mitre.caasd.ea.core.util.CalendarAdapter" />
      </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
```

Which gives this crazy JSON:

```
{
   "foo" : {
      "time" : {
         "type" : "long",
         "value" : 1465250270147
      }
   }
}
```

Now I have no idea why this would happen, nor why the act of telling the element that its type is `String` results in a clearly non-string value, so bonus points if you can explain this.  I could, however, see how that JSON might increase clarity, but the client that is requesting this, does not understand it.  My client existed long before this replacement service, and as such, I really need the JSON to look like this:

```
{
   "foo" : {
      "time" : 1465250094634
   }
}
```

Any idea how I can make that happen?

For the sake of completeness, my CalendarAdapter implementation is this trivial solution:

```
public class CalendarAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Long, Calendar> {
    @Override
    public Calendar unmarshal( Long millis ) throws Exception {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis( millis );
        return calendar;
    }

    @Override
    public Long marshal( Calendar calendar ) throws Exception {
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
}
```

Also, I am using Jersey version 2.22.1.

**---- UPDATE ----**

Switching to Jackson instead of MOXy and using the Adapter (over Converter) works as expected, so for now I will be using that approach.  Perhaps this should be considered a bug in MOXy?